# Angular 2 Tutorial: inline styles defined on styles property of @Component decorator not being applied

Tags: angular

I'm going through the Tour of Heroes tutorial on angular.io, and I'm currently on [this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html). I got to the section titled "Styling our heroes", and I ran into a problem after adding some inline styles. After adding the styles from the tutorial into my own code... I cannot get the styles to apply. Everything still appears un-styled.

I created the project directory using `@angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.0` using `ng new tour-of-heroes`.

and this is what I have so far in `src/app/app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>My Heroes</h2>
    <ul class="heroes">
      <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
        <span class='badge'>{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .selected {
      background-color: #CFD8DC !important;
      color: white;
    }
    .heroes {
      margin: 0 0 2em 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      width: 15em;
    }
    .heroes li {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #EEE;
      margin: .5em;
      padding: .3em 0;
      height: 1.6em;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .heroes li.selected:hover {
      background-color: #BBD8DC !important;
      color: white;
    }
    .heroes li:hover {
      color: #607D8B;
      background-color: #DDD;
      left: .1em;
    }
    .heroes .text {
      position: relative;
      top: -3px;
    }
    .heroes .badge {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: small;
      color: white;
      padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
      background-color: #607D8B;
      line-height: 1em;
      position: relative;
      left: -1px;
      top: -4px;
      height: 1.8em;
      margin-right: .8em;
      border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    }
  `],
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized the problem right as I posted my question... the reason the inline styles are not applying from the `styles` property, is because there is a `styleUrls` property!